# Arrow function stored in State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have this problem, which i don't know if it's a concept wrongly had or a bad implementation of that concept. 
Im doing the pomodoro clock in freecodecamp.org which forces me to use setInterval() function from plain js and in a React component.

Inside the Pomodoro component, every time it gets mounted in the DOM tree should run a setInterval checking for the state and clocking depending on the state of the component. In fact, i can see the state variables change (thanks to the React Debugging tool) but the interval not working

componentdidmount runs after having the component rendered inside the DOM tree and checks the state.status, if its true checks what cycle to run, whether if its the session or break clock.After one timer ends, the other should start immediately.

This timer or interval is stored in the component state and then cleared from the this.state.interval state.

```
class Pomodoro extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     session:1500,
     break:300,
     cycle:true,
     status:false,
     sessionClock:1500,
     breakClock:300,
     interval:0,
    }
 this.addSessionTime = this.addSessionTime.bind(this);
 this.decSessionTime = this.decSessionTime.bind(this);
this.addBreakTime = this.addBreakTime.bind(this);
 this.decBreakTime = this.decBreakTime.bind(this);
 this.pause = this.pause.bind(this);
 this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }

/*Avoided all the other binded functions since they are just setStates*/


componentDidMount() {  

if (this.state.status) 
{


  if (this.state.cycle /* cycle true = session */) 


      { 
        this.setState({
          interval:(setInterval( ()=> {


      if (!this.state.status/*status true = clock running*/ ) {clearInterval(this.state.interval);}
      else 

        {/*begin session clock*/
          if (this.state.sessionClock > 1 /*check if is the last second*/)
          {
        this.setState({sessionClock: this.state.sessionClock - 1});
                      /*take away a second from sessionClock*/
          }

       else {this.setState({cycle:!this.state.cycle, sessionClock:this.state.session}) }
        }                  /*change cycle and restart sessionclock*/

                                                  }
    ,1000)
      )})}

else /*cycle off = break time*/

{

  this.setState({interval: setInterval(()=>{
if (!this.state.status) {clearInterval(this.state.interval)}
    else {
      /*begin break clock*/
          if (this.state.breakClock > 1) 
            {this.setState({breakClock:this.state.breakClock - 1})}
              else {this.setState({cycle:!this.state.cycle, breakClock:this.state.break})}        


          }

},1000)})

}
} 

else  { clearInterval(this.state.interval)}


}
```

the clock isn't working due saving the setInterval into the Component state or its due something else?

EDIT

Added a codepen so you can see the live version and states changing

https://codepen.io/bigclown/pen/bGEpJZb

EDIT II

Erased the componentdidmount method and moved the content to pause() method but now both clocks run at the same time and clocks run faster than intended (might be problem coming from the async state updates in react?)

Comment: So what exactly does "clock isn't working" mean? It's not counting? It's not displaying? It's not shifting from work to break?

Comment: not counting neither shifting, not pausing neither playing

Comment: Storing a reference to an interval is fine, which is what you’re doing—you’re not storing an arrow function. I find the coffee difficult to reason about, though.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton for pointing out the error, what do you mean by "i find the coffe difficult to reason about?"

Comment: I think the issue has something to do with your if/else statements in componentDidMount. componentDidMount is only called once when the component first mounts, and since your default value for this.state.status is false, it's always skipping the if and landing on the else to call `clearInterval`.

Comment: @Maria The componentDidMount() method runs after the component output has been rendered to the DOM.
(taken from reactjs.org) 
is this method called everytime the component gets mounted into the DOM or once?
Whats the method that gets executed after rendering into the dom?

Comment: `cDM` is called *once* on mounting. "Coffee" was an auto-correct for "code". I can't read your code. In fairness, I can't read your coffee either, but that's less relevant. Code turned on its side is not a graph of how awesome it is ;) Cyclomatic complexity kills comprehension.

Comment: Since you only want the timer to start after the play button is clicked you might not need a lifecycle method at all, here's a vastly dumbed down version with just the start/stop button https://codepen.io/meskro7/pen/abdNrVj

Comment: That was my first shot but react async method makes the interval speed up and wrecks the clock. 
this can be seen here 
https://codepen.io/bigclown/pen/bGEpJZb

ALSO its making both clocks work at the same time ?????

Comment: @Maria See edit 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem with your clocks running at the same time and the timer being off is a result of not stopping the old timer before kicking off the new one.

What you might be looking for is the [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) method. This method lets you compare your last state to your current state, and make changes accordingly. Using that method, you can check when we switch from break time to session time, and then stop the old timer to kick off the new one like so:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // We need to check that the new state is different from the old state
    // if it is, stop the old timer, and kick off the new one
    if (prevState.cycle !== this.state.cycle) {
      clearInterval(this.state.interval);
      if (this.state.cycle) {
        // If the cycle switched to session, start the session timer
        this.startSession();
      } else {
        // If the cycle switched to break, start the break timer
        this.startBreak();
      }
    }
  }
```

This way, as long as when your session or break timer reaches 0 you toggle `this.state.cycle`, you'll always be kicking off the new timer.

Check out my new codepen [here](https://codepen.io/meskro7/pen/oNbxKBe?editors=1010) for fully functional code

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your usage of `componentDidMount`. It is invoked when the Component is mounted, which means it is invoked before the user can interact with the screen.

Your check

```
if (this.state.status)
```

Will never be true, as your state sets `status` to false.
Looking at your code, I assume you meant that the *Pause Button* to toggle status to be true, and you felt that the code within `componentDidMount` would run.

---

What you should do however, is move your code into the `pause()` function, as this is actually the trigger for your clock.

From there you can do something similar to:

```
  pause() {
    if (this.state.status === false) {
       // Start your clock, whilst checking `cycle`
    } else {
       clearInterval(this.state.interval);
    }
  }
```

Here is a codepen, where I have refactored your code, but basically moved all the logic into `Pause`. https://codepen.io/stephenyu-the-encoder/pen/zYrqQYE

I've changed all the clocks to start at 5 seconds so it's faster to see it working.

Comment: YES, this was my first attempt but running an interval from a method which isn't componentdidmount() makes the time shift wierd (i think it must be due async updates)